# How to use richtextarea with htmlentites and control the length for database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a **input textarea** use **richtextarea**, user can select text and change to bold, italic

```
 $("#edit2").richtextarea({ toolbar: false }); 
 $("#bold").click(function() { $("#edit2").richtextarea('bold'); });
```

but my output have use `htmlentites` to prevent **xss** output will become **whatever**

my questions are

1. how to output this if I use richtextarea
2. if I use richtextarea, How to control the length for mysql database,

ex. if I set `varchar(10)`, if user input `<b>abcd</b>` this will over than 10 characters. What if malicious user do, `<b>a</b> <b>a</b> <b>a</b>...`

Comment: use the mysql `TEXT` field type?

Comment: i usually use TEXT type for textarea inputs. use `html_entity_decode` to decode the output back on the richtextarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution to output `<b><i>` with `htmlentities`

```
$string=htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$string=str_replace("&lt;b&gt;",'<b>',$string);
$string=str_replace("&lt;/b&gt;",'</b>',$string);
$string=str_replace("&lt;i&gt;",'<i>',$string);
$string=str_replace("&lt;/i&gt;",'</i>',$string);
```

I use `str_replace` replace it.

Is this secure enough?